# mysql insert with dynamic query, need to insert one by one in db only

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have to insert few items which are dynamic from different tables
insert into (field1, field2, field3) values(`<select query fetching one record>,<static value>, <select query fetching multiple records, need to insert one by one>`)

how to insert with foreach in db here? Please help!

Sample Data:
insert into (field1, field2, field3) values(`select myname from table1',0, select payment[1] from table2`);
insert into (field1, field2, field3) values(`select myname from table1',0, select payment[2] from table2`);

Comment: MYSQL does not have a foreach so are you trying to do this from somewhere else (PHP perhaps)?

Comment: Can you show us some sample data and give more info?

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to insert into your table is the combined result of other queries you can just use `INSERT INTO` with `SELECT` and `UNION`.
Something like this

```
INSERT INTO your_table (column1, column2, column3)
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM table2
```